# How can I get a SwiftUI view to display items in chronological order and maintain bindings?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display a list of dates in chronological order whilst using @Binding (The dates are all stored in an array called [DatesInfo] which I believe is the source of truth)

```
struct DatesView: View {
    @Binding var dates: [DatesInfo]

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach($dates, editActions: .delete) { $date in
                CardView(thisDate: date)
            }
            .background(NavigationLink("", destination: DetailView(thisDate: $date)).opacity(0))
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen how to order a list by date however I can't get them to work with the bindings needed for the Navigation link thing.

Comment: Just sort the array itself, onAppear, onChange, task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For more information, you can read this article [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/sort()) or this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/beginners/how-to-store-ordered-data-in-arrays)

```
struct DatesView: View {
        @Binding var dates: [DatesInfo]

    var sortedDates: [DatesInfo] {
        dates.sorted { 
            $0.date < $1.date 
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sortedDates, id: \.id) { date in
                CardView(thisDate: date)
                    .background(
                        NavigationLink("", destination: DetailView(thisDate: $dates[dates.firstIndex(of: date)!]))
                            .opacity(0)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```